# Mule dotnet connector not recognizing Integer

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I was doing a sample flow for studying dotnet connector in mule.
I was able to execute a sample dll hello world method via mule. But one of my dll method is returning an integer value and it is not executing, showing an error
 "Failed to invoke execute. Message payload is of type: NullPayload"

My dotnet method is

```
 public static int TestInt()
    {            
        return 1 ;
    }
```

and my method name given in mule dotnet connector is

> MuleUtilConsol.Utils, MuleUtilConsol, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null | TestIn) -> System.Integer

Can anyone tell me how can I get an integer value from dll method via mule.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I know nothing about mule, but I would guess that it's because your method is static.

Comment: I tried without  'static' still the same issue

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace on Mule please?